# Travis CI not using master branch cache

Tags: travis-ci, carthage

I'm using **Carthage** as my project package manager and **Travis CI**.

The problem that I'm facing is that yesterday, Travis did create a cache from `master` branch correctly, as you can see in the picture below, and everything was working fine.

[image]

But today, when I did switch to another branch and pushed changes to it, Travis is not fetching the cache that it has made from `master` branch. Instead, it's creating a new `cache` for this branch that I've created. I want it to use master cache always, and don't try to create a `cache` for each branch that I create from `master`.

How should I proceed to achieve that?

Source Files:
`.travis.yml`

```
#Xcode 9.4 image default contents: https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-07-19-xcode9-4-default-announce
#Need to create: "if: branch = master" and "if: branch = development"

language: swift
os: osx
osx_image: xcode10
sudo: required

cache:
directories:
- Carthage

before_install:
# Update Homebrew
- brew update
# Clean install Carthage
- brew uninstall --force carthage
- brew install carthage
- brew cask install fastlane
# Provide travis machines with github access
- echo -e "machine github.com\n  login $CI_USER_TOKEN" >> ~/.netrc
# Print script to avoid travis_wait from stopping build process
- while sleep 480m; do echo "=====[ $SECONDS seconds, Carthage still building... ]====="; done &
# Carthage Bootstrap
- carthage bootstrap --cache-builds --platform ios,watchos --no-use-binaries
# Stop Print script
- kill %1

script:
- fastlane beta
```